# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (s_n)^2=L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $L \in \Bbb R$ and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = L.$$

Use the formal definition of a limit to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n^2 = L^2.$$

Could anyone help prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use the fact that a *convergent* sequence of real numbers is *bounded*, and one may observe that
$$
s_n^2-L^2=(s_n-L)(s_n+L).
$$

Answer (score 0):

or
$|s_n^2-L^2|=|(s_n-L)^2+2L(s_n-L)|$

and use the triangular inequality.

finally, remember that if $|U_n-l|<V_n$

and $limV_n=0$  then $limU_n=l$.